# Is there a vSphere vSAN SDK API option to set VMKernal Advanced Setting

Tags: python, vmware-vsphere, vsan

I am writing a script to automate shutting down a vSAN cluster (yes I know 7.03 know has a button), based on [this knowledge base article](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vsan-monitoring.doc/GUID-31B4F958-30A9-4BEC-819E-32A18A685688.html).

I am at the part where it wants us to call a script on each ESXi host.

```
esxcfg-advcfg -s 1 /VSAN/IgnoreClusterMemberListUpdates
```

I could use a Python lib like `paramiko` but that means I would need to keep SSH turned on all the time.

Is there a way to use `pyVmomi` or vSphere/vSAN API to perform the same task?